# How to repartition cell with matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix (a log file) structured as follows:

```
Date              hour         sender     receiver  message
7/14/2014         19/54/8      C5         S         a
7/14/2014         19/54/9      S          C5        c
7/14/2014         19/54/10     C5         S         a
7/14/2014         19/54/11     S          C5        b
7/14/2014         19/54/12     C5         S         d
7/14/2014         19/54/13     C5         S         h
7/14/2014         19/54/14     C5         S         i
7/14/2014         19/54/15     S          C5        k
7/14/2014         19/54/16     C5         S         p 
7/14/2014         19/54/17     C3         S         a
7/14/2014         19/54/18     S          C3        c
7/14/2014         19/54/19     C3         S         a
………………………………………………………………..
```

I want to create the occurrence matrix from this file which contains the numbers of occurrences of couples of messages by each day and for each client see the example:

```
    C5  S   a
    S   C5  c
    C5  S   a
    S   C5  b
    C5  S   d
    C5  S   h
    C5  S   i
    C5  S   k
    C2  S   a
    S   C2  c
    C2  S   a
    S   C2  b
```

The occurrence matrix is as follow:

```
    C5    C2    C3   c4
ac  5     4     2    3
ca  3     2     1    2
ab  1     1     0    1
bd  2     3     4    1
dh  2     3     4    0
ik  1     1     1    1
```

Any help please?

Comment: Take a look at `unique` and `accumarray`.

Comment: Regarding `unique`, look specially at its third output